# Como popular um objeto carregado com populate no Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest, express.js, mongoose

Tenho uma duvida, se eu ja tenho uma query sendo populada no Mongoose, e ela for populada com um model que também tem relação, existe um meio de popular ele também?

Por exemplo:

Tenho meu model de `Os`:

```
const mongoose = require('../config/database');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const OsSchema = new Schema({

    nome: {type: String, required: true},
    cnpjcpf: {type: String, required: true},
    dataservico: { type:Date, required:true},
    datagarantia: { type:Date, required:true},
    duracao: { type:Number},
    dificuldade: {type: Number},
    vendedor: {type: String, required: true},
    score: {type: Number, required: true},
    done: {type: Boolean, required:true},
    created: { type:Date, default:Date.now()},
    operador:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Operador'}],
    pragas:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Praga'}],
    produtos:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Produto'}],
    reforco:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Reforco'}],
    
},{toJSON:{virtuals:true}});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Os', OsSchema);
```

Mas meu model de `reforco` também tem relações:

```
const mongoose = require('../config/database');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ReforcoShema = new Schema({

    dataservico: { type:Date, required:true},
    duracao: { type:Date},
    done: {type: Boolean, required:true},
    programado: {type: Boolean, required:true},
    operador:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Operador'}],
    pragas:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Praga'}],
    produtos:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Produto'}],
    created: { type:Date, default:Date.now()}

},{toJSON:{virtuals:true}});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Reforco', ReforcoShema);
```

Quando faço uma query nas `Os` e populo o `reforco`, ele tras o reforço normalmente, mas só trás o `ID` das relações do reforço, existe um meio de popular eles também?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você teria que usar o populate para multiplos níveis. No seu caso você pode tentar passar um array contento regras de campos para popular.

Um exemplo para o seu caso, vamos popular o campo `reforco` e deste campo queremos tambem popular o campo `operador`:

```js
Os.find({ nome: req.body.nome })     // filtro qualquer
  .populate({
    path: 'reforco',                 // populamos o "reforco"
    populate: [{ path: 'operador' }] // passamos um array com objetos
                                     // com os campos a serem populados
                                     // neste caso o campo "operador"
  })
```

Se quise popular mais campos, passe mais objetos para o array:

```js
Os.find({ nome: req.body.nome })
  .populate({
    path: 'reforco',
    populate: [{ path: 'operador' }, { path: 'pragas' }, { path: 'produtos' }]
  })
```

Isso se chama *Populating across multiple levels* e podemos encontrar na [documentacao do mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate).

Comment: Isso funciona em quantos níveis for necessário certo?

Comment: sim, mas fique atento para a questao de performance pois popular varios campos, podem afetar o desempenho da consulta.